# MySQL Large Query Tuning

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have been given the below MySQL query by another developer and it's very slow, I have tried to tune it up by specifying columns rather than * and using a between statement rather than a lengthly IN statement but it's still very very slow.

I would appreciate any help in how I can get a quicker page load from this!

Background: the code is for a wordpress page that lists properties with any availability within the specified dates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(wposts.ID), wposts.*, wpostmeta5.meta_value as 'calendar' 
FROM DvCs_posts wposts 
LEFT JOIN DvCs_postmeta wpostmeta5 ON ( wposts.ID = wpostmeta5.post_id AND wpostmeta5.meta_key = 'calendar' ) 
INNER JOIN DvCs_bookingtypes bookingtypes ON ( wpostmeta5.meta_value = bookingtypes.booking_type_id ) 
LEFT JOIN DvCs_term_relationships tr ON ( wposts.ID = tr.object_id AND tr.term_taxonomy_id = 1 ) 
WHERE wposts.post_type = 'post' 
AND(
SELECT tt.term_id FROM DvCs_term_taxonomy tt WHERE tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id AND tt.term_id = 1 ) IS NULL 
AND (
   ( SELECT booking_id FROM DvCs_bookingdates bd2 WHERE bd2.booking_id IN ( (SELECT booking_id FROM DvCs_booking bookings WHERE bookings.booking_type = bookingtypes.booking_type_id ) ) AND bd2.booking_date BETWEEN '2014-06-27' and '2014-06-28' LIMIT 1 ) IS NULL 
OR ( SELECT booking_id FROM DvCs_bookingdates bd2 WHERE bd2.booking_id IN ( (SELECT booking_id FROM DvCs_booking bookings WHERE bookings.booking_type = bookingtypes.booking_type_id ) ) AND bd2.booking_date BETWEEN '2014-07-04' and '2014-07-10' LIMIT 1 ) IS NULL 
OR ( SELECT booking_id FROM DvCs_bookingdates bd2 WHERE bd2.booking_id IN ( (SELECT booking_id FROM DvCs_booking bookings WHERE bookings.booking_type = bookingtypes.booking_type_id ) ) AND bd2.booking_date BETWEEN '2014-07-11' and '2014-07-17' LIMIT 1 ) IS NULL 
OR ( SELECT booking_id FROM DvCs_bookingdates bd2 WHERE bd2.booking_id IN ( (SELECT booking_id FROM DvCs_booking bookings WHERE bookings.booking_type = bookingtypes.booking_type_id ) ) AND bd2.booking_date BETWEEN '2014-06-28' and '2014-06-29' LIMIT 1 ) IS NULL 
OR ( SELECT booking_id FROM DvCs_bookingdates bd2 WHERE bd2.booking_id IN ( (SELECT booking_id FROM DvCs_booking bookings WHERE bookings.booking_type = bookingtypes.booking_type_id ) ) AND bd2.booking_date BETWEEN '2014-07-05' and '2014-07-11' LIMIT 1 ) IS NULL 
OR ( SELECT booking_id FROM DvCs_bookingdates bd2 WHERE bd2.booking_id IN ( (SELECT booking_id FROM DvCs_booking bookings WHERE bookings.booking_type = bookingtypes.booking_type_id ) ) AND bd2.booking_date BETWEEN '2014-07-12' and '2014-07-18' LIMIT 1 ) IS NULL
) 
AND wposts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND wposts.id NOT IN
(
SELECT ID FROM DvCs_posts p 
INNER JOIN DvCs_term_relationships r ON p.id = r.object_id 
INNER JOIN DvCs_term_taxonomy t ON r.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_taxonomy_id 
WHERE p.post_type = 'post' 
AND p.post_status = 'publish' 
AND t.term_id = 29
)
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: Could you provide some table structure and sample data as well? That could be quite useful in understanding where and what the bottlenecks are?

Comment: Can you share also `EXPLAIN EXTENDED <Your slow query>` output?

Comment: What does explain select distict ... say about the query?

Comment: The slow part are all SELECT within WHERE.